# Problems with PHP file_get_contents() on RHEL 6

Tags: php, linux, apache, proxy, file-get-contents

Ok, I have two Linux boxes running behind a proxy server. Both boxes are set to bypass the filtering by connecting on port 801.

Box A - Fedora Core 12 / PHP 5.3.1

Box B - RHEL 6 / PHP 5.3.3

On Box A I am able to use file_get_contents() to conenct to an external site.

```
<?php
$opts = array(
              'http' => array(
                              'proxy' => 'tcp://10.136.132.1:801',
                              'request_fulluri' => true
                             )
             );

$cxContext = stream_context_set_default($opts);
echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
```

This results in Google's homepage being displayed.

On Box B I run the same code, but get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Both boxes are on the same network and behind the same proxy server.  Is there a setting I am missing in Apache or PHP that will allow file_get_contents to work on Box B?

Comment: What does print_r($http_response_header) tell you?

Comment: On Box B $http_response_header is an undefined variable.  On Box A it produced header info in an array.  Does something need to be switched on to get this working?

Comment: If the response headers indicate a 4xx error, it's probably not a PHP problem

Comment: I don't get anything back - On Box B PHP does not see $http_response_header as a system function.  It thinks it is a variable that has not been declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have SELinux enabled, it blocks any outgoing connections by Apache by default. Try running this in your shell as root:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

More info on SELinux booleans can be found here:
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Comment: That works.  SELinux was indeed the problem.  Thank you for your help Kaivosukeltaja.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That could be because google blocks requests that seem to come from Bot or Script.
Maybe because Box A sets additional headers when requesting to google.

Try to open other website on Box b